# PChart - Show a fixed number of lablels in X-Axis

Tags: pchart

How to show only a fixed number of labels in X-Axis ??

I have tried "LabelSkip", but I think it works only with an interval and not with fixed number of labels.

Here is a print-screen of my chart: 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you using pChart 1 or pChart2 ?

This can be achived in pChart 1 using `setFixedScale`

To draw a scale with a maximum value of 10 with 5 points use the following command before drawing the scale

```
$Graph->setFixedScale(0,10,5);
```

Comment: In pChart2, I found this to be the only way

$myPicture->drawScale(array("MinDivHeight"=>50);

So if your chart area is 400px wide, this will show 8 labels. Changing it to 100px will only show 4 labels.

Comment: Does this not work for you anymore? If you unaccept the answer, it would be great to know what you used that did work for you.

Comment: $myPicture->drawScale(array("MinDivHeight"=>50); don't work for me

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been a while since this was asked, but it may help someone:

```
$maxXLabels = 5; // How many labels on-screen?

$labelSkip = floor( count( $timestamp ) / $maxXLabels ); // how many should we skip?
$myPicture->drawScale(array("LabelSkip"=>$labelSkip));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used 
"LabelSkip"=>(count($series)/10)
to have 10 labels on the X axis

Works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Joel Deutscher's answer worked for me.  I would have up voted it, but I do not have enough stackoverflow reputation for that.

It works exactly as he said: Chart Width / MinDivHeight  = Number of labels on the chart.

Here's my code

```
$scaleSettings = array("DrawXLines"=>FALSE,"Mode"=>SCALE_MODE_START0,"GridR"=>0,"GridG"=>0,"GridB"=>0,"GridAlpha"=>10,"Pos"=>SCALE_POS_TOPBOTTOM, "MinDivHeight" => 50);

$pchart->chart->drawScale($scaleSettings);
```